# How to write a python script to copy files from without copying files it already has?

Tags: python, copy, python-2.5

I am an amateur, so please have patience. So here is what I am in need of. I need to move files from one folder to another. In the destination folder the new files will then be sorted out manually. This script will be running every five minutes via pycron, a windows service. I need to know how to write this script, so that it won't copy things it already has. Do I have to create an additional file to keep track of that?

Thank you all for your help!

Edit: If it could be python 2.5 compatible, that would be great.

Comment: Do you have an initial attempt? If so, please post it, and it'll be easier to direct you from there.

Comment: I have some overly complicated code, that was wrote by someone else, that grabs these files, reads some stuff from a database, renames the files according to the database, and moves them to a different folder. It also keeps track of what has already been copied over via a .dat file. I was going to try to modify that code, but it seemed like I would have to gut a lot of it and rework it anyway.

Comment: The code below doesn't use a separate file to keep track of things, but it only works with directories that are identical to each other from the parent directory on.

Comment: This [backup files recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/191017/) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a barebones code that will synchronize two directories if they have the same structure within the directory.

```
import shutil
import os
#Assuming your folders are identical for synchronization purposes
root_src_dir = "Path\To\Source"
root_dst_dir = "Path\To\Dest"
for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        #dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        #Decides whether or not to replace files in the destination
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(root_dst_dir,dst_file)): #EDIT HERE.
            continue
        else:
            print "Copying", dst_file
            shutil.copy(src_file,os.path.join(root_dst_dir,dst_file)) #EDIT HERE
```

This will automatically create a "copy" of the source directory to the destination directory. It will create subdirectories that are missing and copy files in those specific locations to the destination directory only if the file does not yet exist in the destination.

If you want make sure files are identitcal or not, then you'll probably want to look into [filecmp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) or hashes(below) to check if you've copied the file before.

```
import hashlib
def cmpHash(file1,file2):
    """ Compares two files' hashes to determine duplicates. This doesn't work out so well, possibly due to different metadata"""
    hash1 = open(file1,'r').read()
    hash2 = open(file2,'r').read()
    #returns true if the files are the same - otherwise, false.
    return  hashlib.sha512(file1).hexdigest() == hashlib.sha512(file2).hexdigest()
```

Example: (NO LONGER TRUE AFTER EDIT).

```
DriveA:\SomeDirectory\SourceDirectory\-Stuff-
DriveB:\DestDirectory\-Stuff-
#All -Stuff- from the SourceDirectory will be copied to DestDirectory, regardless of directories infront of Source/Dest Directory
```

Comment: The only issue I see with that, is that the files that are moved to the destination folder will be moved manually by people into other folders, so the code would be sending files it already sent.

Comment: It's easy to change that if you're copying files to a single directory.

Comment: I've made edits that would only check in the dest directory, and copy files from anywhere in source directory to the dest directory in ONLY that directory.

Comment: In addition to checking if a file exists in the destination directory, it need to at least also compare modification dates to see if the files are really the same.

Comment: filecmp and hashes will do that for you. it's already included in the post